# CORS Ajax calls create new session

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I would like to create a counter by using a session. But if I call the counter via Ajax the session is always reseted. Whats wrong?

Here my PHP-File:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 Ok");

         if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
            session_start();
         };


        if (!isset($_SESSION['zaehler'])) {
          $_SESSION['zaehler'] = 1;
        } else {
          $_SESSION['zaehler']++;
        };
        echo "Zähler: ".$_SESSION['zaehler'];
```

my Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: { whatever:'cool' },
   url: "http://www.huntinggrounds.de/test.php",
   xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, //by trying this I will get a cors error by browser.
   crossDomain: true,
   success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);
   },
   beforeSend: function(xhr){
       xhr.withCredentials = true;
   }
});
```

By calling the file [test.php](http://www.huntinggrounds.de/test.php) it will counts up. By calling via ajax it always starts with 1. See [Ajax Testfile](http://huntinggrounds.de/glitch) by just clicking in window and look at your console.

Any Idea? THX for any hint in advance.

Comment: I don't know PHP anymore, but shouldn't you start the session first? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php